# Add "COUNT" column in SSRS in place of details rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Apologies for this very newb-like question.  I have some detail data that I want to group... I have added three group by columns (LOB, Event Classification, Assigned) to my table and want to add a third (Count) that counts the number of rows in the third (Assigned) group.  At the moment I do this simply by adding a CountRows() column within the last (inner most) group.  This is all I want to show.  But I am forced to add a details column that I do not need (in this case I have "Amount").  Please see figure below:

[image]

Basically, I like what I have, except that I don't need that last "Amount" column.  If I hide it, the row heights stay the same (i.e., their height is determined by the number of rows in the hidden column).  I'm guessing I'm missing something pretty fundamental here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://consulting.risualblogs.com/blog/2013/06/28/tablix-body-must-contain-at-least-one-column-ssrs/ I found:

1. Right click the last column, ‘Column Visibility’, ‘Hide’
   2: On the ‘Row Groups’ or ‘Column Groups’, right click the ‘Details’ grouping and press delete, but only delete the grouping, not the associated rows and just delete the data in the last column.

Comment: H ProN, It doesn' work, once Details Grouping deleted you will loose multiple bars on this line so only single line will left.

Comment: It worked back in Jan 2015.  Maybe the functionality has changed since then.  It was 3.5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to place your values in the header of the last group defined which in your case is "Assigned". And remove the detail column. This should allow you to aggregate your values outward. The Count column  would be a second group header for the Assigned group.

Comment: Thanks... but I don't quite follow.  If I attempt to delete the detail column I get an error "Tablix body must contain at least one column".  How do I place "values in the header of the last group defined [Assigned]"?

Comment: ...change your detail column to be grouped by Assigned. Basically push all columns down one. You can have a report with no detail row.